# Can one set the color of a cell if the content of that cell is also present in a defined range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a spreadsheet that can be found [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iC1cx4qTMnM_wcZt83b4ghmtFIvpErtNriMbXnEIQ5Q/edit?usp=sharing). The idea is that people who are attending the master's program can use this sheet to get a better grasp of what courser are available.

I have managed to create drop down menus such that one can pick only the valid courses for a specific time slot. I would however also like to *color* the cell depending on which column the text is taken from.

Example

If someone picks "Types for Programs and Proofs" (LP1, MPALG) I want that cell to be green, because the course is owned by MPALG. However, if somenone picks Quantum Mechanics I want the cell to become red, because it is owned by MPCAS.

Can ths be achieved?

Cheers

Comment: I think that could be achieved with conditional formatting and some cleaver regex. I'll get back if I figure it out.

Comment: Conditional formatting is most definitely the way to go, but I was unable to get it to work.

Comment: I have added the following conditional format to each cell `=COUNTA( IFERROR( FILTER( <range> , <range>=<cell> ) ) )`. It has to be done 4 times per cell (because I want 4 colors). <cell> is the cell you are formatting and <range> is the range of the courses in that specific column.
   
Example: Edit the conditional formatting for B5 and set: `=COUNTA( IFERROR( FILTER( B11:B40 , B11:B40=B5 ) ) )` to make the cell responsive to courses owned by MPALG.

  
There must be a better way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

The body of your question is incomprehensible, but the Title is clear enough:

> Can one set the color of a cell if the content of that cell is also present in a defined range?

Yes, for example with:

```
=countif(indirect("NamedRange1"),indirect("NamedRange2"))>0
```